# Make socket connection with push of button

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter, raspberry-pi3

So I'm running two raspberry pi's. One is acting as a hotspot (can't remember the exact software, DCP something?) and the other is connected to it through the WiFi.

Anyway, I want this connection to proceed on bootup, but the issue is, it will only work when I run the programs at the exact same time, and loops seem to fail it.

So here's my server.

```
Host = '' #I have my specific address here
PORT = 8000
s= socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

def CamConn():
    s.bind((Host, PORT))
    s.listen(24) # I eventually want 24 rpi connected
    Conn, addr = s.accept()
    Conn.settimeout(1)
```

CamConn() is called via tkinter button.

My client

```
HOST= ''
PORT= 8000
s= socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
```

Biggest issue here is that they sort of connect, but don't really... The address becomes "in use" and I have to reboot the server to get it free again. I've tried using exceptions, but it runs into the same issue. I honestly have no idea why it's only half connecting?

Edit:

Guys, I'm going to put the clients in a tuple eventually, so there is no need for threading.

I'm using an after mainloop to ensure that the sockets and send and receive what's necessary.

All I'm asking is why this connection won't work when called on via a button. The client will hang, until the button is pressed in which it will recognise a connection, but it will fail to create a connection that can send or receive data.

Edit 2: I should also mention that I'm broadcasting identical information to all the other clients, every second. The only time the server recieves data is if an option is selected in which a photo will be sent.

Comment: if you want 24 clients then you will need `threads`

Comment: `accept()` waits till client connect so it blocks program - you have to run it in  `thread`

Comment: I'm fine with blocking, that's not the issue. Also I don't need to thread as I'm going to place all the clients in a tuple

Comment: `accept()` will block tkinter `mainloop()`

Comment: I am aware, but I only need them to connect once (its a machine), and then it has an afterloop which works fast enough to not be a problem. Please just tell me how to make them connect.

Comment: Using tkInter for a server using sockets is difficult. You have to fit the handling of sockets into the tkinter event loop. This is too broad an issue for a single SO question.

Comment: I've already worked out the event loop, I just need to know why the socket won't bind when called upon as an event. If the programs start at the same time, it connects and works fine, however when using it as a callable (I have a button to try to enable more connections) the connection seems to recognise a connection, but not make one, as evident when I used exception loops.

Comment: this part of code look correctly - maybe show rest of code. How do you assign to button?

Comment: Button(master, text="find cameras", command= CamConn)      # I've done printing and it does launch the function.

Comment: See, I want the client to be blocked and wait for a connection when available, and the server, well I'd like the button to be able to accept the connection. But this for some reason fails, usually resulting in an address in use error (I think errno 98?). If it's hardcoded to accept it works fine (have all the stuff at the start of the program) but when using it on start-up (screens won't be available) it must accept a connection, because it moves on, but then it won't receive any data at all.

Comment: first you have to run `accept()` (which will wait for client - client will not wait for server if you don't run `accept()` first) and when it returns address then you can display GUI with button to accept/confirm connection. After you click button you can send, receive data.

Comment: So, are you saying I should loop the client? Should I move over to socket.server? I don't need to go asynchronously, but I do need a method to make new socket connections (essentially incase they don't automatically do it)

Comment: I had to check something - you have to `bind()` and `listen()` at start, not when you click button because client will not wait till you run `bind()` `listen()`. BTW: try `s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)` before `bind()` if you get `[Error 98] Address already in use`

Comment: Can you explain what s.bind does? Is it specific to the program or to the server- client relationship?

Comment: Ok, address error is gone. That's fantastic thank you, however, I still get the issue where the client achieves the whole "connection" thing, but then won't send or recieve. Like, it sort of jumps the gun?

Comment: Oh, so I found out connection is not a problem now (was. But we have solved it), now it seems to never recieve. I wonder, could it be because there is no return in the function called, and thus the main programs conn is different to the functions conn?